# duda recursividad

Tags: c++, loops, recursión, iteraciones

tengo un código de ejemplo de un procedimiento de impresión de manera recursiva en orden inverso del contenido de una lista que no entiendo. Este es el código:

Mi duda: yo me imaginé el funcionamiento de esto, pensé que más o menos sería así: empieza la ejecución en el primer nodo, llegamos a `if (n != NULL)`, efectivamente, no es NULL, llegamos a la llamada recursiva, volvemos a empezar pero en el siguiente nodo y así hasta llegar al último nodo, cuando lleguemos al último nodo qué pasa en la llamada recursiva? porque `n->get_next()` es `NULL`. Se agradece explicación de cómo se deshace la llamada recursiva

¿debería ser write_reverse1 la llamada recursiva no?

```
template <class T>
ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse1(dll_node_t<T>* n, ostream& os) const {

        if (n != NULL)
            reverse1(n->get_next(), os);
        else
            n->write(os);

        return os;
    }
```

este segundo método para qué sirve?

```
    template <class T>
    ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse1(ostream& os) const {

        reverse1(head_, os);

        return os;
    }
```

muchas gracias

Comment: que es el metodo reverse1? me faltaria algun dato. y eso solo imprime el ultimo nodo.. el resto no los imprime

Comment: no sabria que hacer con el enunciado.. centremosnos en tu problema..

Comment: @gbianchi, me equivoque de enunciado, disculpas, es este: Impleméntese el método recursivo de la clase dll_t ostream& dll_t<T>::write_reverse(dll_node_t<T>* n, ostream& os) const que muestra en orden inverso el contenido de la lista enlazada invocante a partir del nodo n. Sólo 
se podrá utilizar el método dll_node_t* get_next() de la clase dll_node_t para acceder al elemento siguiente. En ningún caso se permitirá utilizar el método dll_node_t* get_prev().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en pseudocodigo.. (te dejo la implementacion a vos)

```
imprimir-reversa(nodo n, lista l)
{
    si n != null
    {
      imprimir-reversa(l.next-nodo, l)
    }
    imprimirnodo(n)
}
```

por lo tanto, si, la llamada recursiva tendria que ser write_reverse1.

Comment: tenia dudas con el codigo, el ejercicio lo encontré resuelto

Comment: Pero no entiendo cual es la duda

Comment: no entiendo el codigo del ejercicio resuelto

Comment: Es q como te dije en el comentario arriba. No se q es reverse1 (no hay una definicion de esa funcion) y la otra no es recursiva y solo imprime el ultimo.

Comment: en la llamada recursiva hay un pequeño error, igual eso te confundió, debería ser write_reverse1(...) en vez de reverse1.